# H4 work from home (remotely)

Tags: working-visas, freelance, h4-visa

Is it legally allowed to work from home using dependent visa.
I am shifting to USA in a couple of months and my wife is also working in India.
Her company accepts to work from home instead of resigning the job. 
Is it allowed for H4.? All the salary transaction, tax will be payed in India.

Is it allowed to do any freelancing job on H4?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not allowed. Also, even if you do break the law working from home while in a status that doesn't allow employment, the US income tax must still be paid. After all, that's how they got Al Capone.

It doesn't matter where the employer is.